# How to format results from rest api sharepoint jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, html

I am using rest api to get results in below format but how shall append my result to get in desired format and on click document should open new tab

my code

```
function getListData() {        
      var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$top=1000&$select=Created,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName,FileLeafRef,ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl&$expand=Author/Id&$filter=FSObjType eq 0";
      console.log(fullUrl);
      $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
      });
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
      var listItemInfo = " ";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {  
            if (data.d.results[i].FileSystemObjectType != 1) { 
        listItemInfo += "<div class=panel-heading><h4><a href='"+data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl+"'>"+data.d.results[i].FileLeafRef+"</a></h4><p>"+data.d.results[i].Created+""+data.d.results[i].Author.FirstName+""+data.d.results[i].Author.LastName+"</p></div>";
            
            }  
        } 
     
        console.log(listItemInfo);
         $("#divResults").html(listItemInfo);
      };
```

result i am getting

[image]

expected results

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are require to format the date in MM/DD/YYYY and spacing between first name and last name.

Add below method to get formatted date.

```
 function getFormattedDate(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
    month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

    var day = date.getDate().toString();
    day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

    return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

- Replace **listItemInfo** line in *onQuerySucceeded* method with following line.

```
listItemInfo += "<div class=panel-heading><h4><a href='"+data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl+"'>"+data.d.results[i].FileLeafRef+"</a></h4><p>"+getFormattedDate(data.d.results[i].Created)+", "+data.d.results[i].Author.FirstName+" "+data.d.results[i].Author.LastName+"</p></div>";
```

- Final code will looks like below

```
function getListData() {
    var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$top=1000&$select=Created,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName,FileLeafRef,ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl&$expand=Author/Id&$filter=FSObjType eq 0";
    console.log(fullUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
    });
}


function getFormattedDate(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
    month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

    var day = date.getDate().toString();
    day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

    return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}


function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var listItemInfo = " ";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
        if (data.d.results[i].FileSystemObjectType != 1) {
            listItemInfo += "<div class=panel-heading><h4><a href='" + data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl + "'>" + data.d.results[i].FileLeafRef + "</a></h4><p>" + getFormattedDate(data.d.results[i].Created) + ", " + data.d.results[i].Author.FirstName + " " + data.d.results[i].Author.LastName + "</p></div>";

        }
    }

    console.log(listItemInfo);
    $("#divResults").html(listItemInfo);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options.

1. You could use the native JavaScript method `toLocaleString()` on the `Date` type to format the date:

`data.d.results[i].Created.toLocaleDateString("default", {dateStyle: "short"})`

2. You could use a library like moment.js:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js">  </script>`

`var createdMoment = moment(data.d.results[i].Created);`
`createdMoment.format("MM/DD/YYYY")`

I would recommend using moment.js as it provides more options on how the date may be formatted.

Resources:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/